# CSS img srcset media query for portrait orientation

Tags: css, orientation, srcset

I have two images, one I need for landscape orientation and one for portrait.

Using `<picture>`, i can use standard media queries, but `<picture>` is not supported on Safari, so i want to use `<img srcset>`. I can't find any information, how to adress portrait orientation for any device in `srcset`.

Any help?

Comment: AFAIK srcset only supports pixel densities, no complete media queries. But what's stopping you from using a background-image and an actual media query in the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `srcset` for art direction. Use `<picture>` and [picturefill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

safari now supports <picture> . Here is code to display different images for portrait and landscape modes.

```
<picture>
    <source media="(orientation: landscape)" srcset="landscape.jpg">
    <source media="(orientation: portrait)" srcset="portrait.jpg">
    <img src="fallback-image.jpg">
</picture>
```